# Can I storage service account key into a bucket in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm creating an account service with terraform, the idea is at the moment it creates, the private key saves into a bucket also created by terraform, it's possible?

Comment: If you use terraform on GCP, use impersonation instead. Service account key file are done for external system without OIDC authentication possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing preventing you from storing keys in a storage bucket, but you would be better served to store the keys in a more secure way like [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there are some problems with this approach and you could end up having some issues.

- First, you are storing a SA in a simple bucket, so anyone with access to the console would be able to download that key.
- If you have any problem with your terraform setup or need to change something in your bucket, you could lose your SA.

As recommended, you can use the Secret Manager to store it, but if you don't want to use any service, you have some options like:

- You can create the SA encrypting the private key with a PGP Key, and it will be stored at terraform's state
- If you are using `git` you can create the SA via terraform, save the key on the repo and use `git-crypt` to encrypt that file, so only you will be able to see its content but you can add other GPG keys to the repo.